# How to interface with generic IR RGB LED controller?

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led

I want to hook up an arduino to one of those generic RGB LED controllers, you see them everywhere, they are these little white boxes with power input and RGB strip plug and an IR LED lead. Is there a way to take to the IR + and - and connect them the arduino? Then spoof an IR signal to control the control module? I want to do it this way because I already own both the arduino and control module and that module handles the power for the LEDs. All I am hoping I have to do is send the controller the hex value for the IR command through the the arduino in order to control it. Here's a link to what the module looks like and the remote it comes

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ASHQQKI/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_htMywb1W85962](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ASHQQKI)

Answer (score 1):

The [IRRemote Library](http://www.righto.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html) is a good starting point, but you'll probably need a RAW mode.   I've got a couple IR controllers from different companies, and they use different codes for the same things.

Comment: Mine were basic NEC protocol.